# How to design/develop a JSP page which has to show 15 profile pics with their names in it?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have a JSP page, which is used to show 15 profile pics with their names. Similar to Orkut Friend List.

I am bringing information(friends list) from DB and showing it through Servlet.I need directions on how to display profile pic with their names on it.

I think it will have 15 html div's (3 horizontal and 5 vertical). How should i bring Information from Servlet response to JSP page in each of div's. Or is this correct method to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the servlet store it as request or perhaps session attribute before forwarding to JSP.

```java
List<ProfilePicture> profilePictures = profilePictureService.list(15);
request.setAttribute("profilePictures", profilePictures);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Let the JSP generate the HTML accordingly using JSTL `<c:forEach>`.

```html
<div id="profilePictures">
    <c:forEach items="${profilePictures}" var="profilePicture">
        <div class="profilePicture">
            <img src="${profilePicture.url}" width="200" height="300" />
            <br /><c:out value="${profilePicture.description}" />
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Throw in some CSS to style and position it properly.

```css
#profilePictures {
    width: 630px;
}

.profilePicture {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```